# Connecting netbeans (JAVA) to MYSQL

Tags: java, mysql, database, netbeans, connection

The problem is when I run this code, I always get answer COL12 instead of getting all the columns with data like I am getting in `MYSQL` workbench. I need to get same values. Moreover when I use this query "DELETE FROM test WHERE col1 = 2;" in netbeans I get Error Exception.

Here is my Code I wrote in Netbeans.
    package sams;

```
import java.sql.*;  
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.sql.DriverManager;




public class Temp_Class {



public static void main(String[] args){

    try {

String query="SELECT * FROM test";
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection con=      DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/JavaProject", "root",  "19881990");
        Statement st=con.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery(query);
        rs.next();
        String sname= rs.getString(2);
 System.out.println(sname);
con.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {

            System.out.println("Error");

      }


    }



}
```

I have made table test in `MYSQL` Workbench, with columns="col1, col2, col3" with values="1, COL11, COL12" and "2, COL21, COL22";

This is the code I use to delete a value in DB. . . but getting Error Exception.

```
public static void main(String[] args){

    try {


        String deletesql="DELETE FROM test WHERE col1 = 2";

        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection con= DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/JavaProject", "root", "19881990");
        Statement st=con.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery(select);

        Statement ds=con.createStatement();
        ResultSet dsrow=ds.executeQuery(deletesql);

        dsrow.next();
        String ds1= dsrow.getString(1);
        String ds2= dsrow.getString(2);
        String ds3= dsrow.getString(3);
        System.out.println(ds1+" "+ ds2+" "+ds3);

        con.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {

        System.out.println("Error");

    }


}
```

Comment: Can you show the code and the complete stacktrace?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`String sname= rs.getString(2);` returns one column from the resultSet. If you want to have all columns you have to use:

```
String sname0= rs.getString(0);
String sname1= rs.getString(1);
String sname2= rs.getString(2);
```

Comment: String sname= rs.getString(1);
            String sname12= rs.getString(2);
            String sname13= rs.getString(3);
            System.out.println(sname+" "+ sname12+" "+sname13);

Comment: i wrote the above code now. now i am able to get the entire row. Can u please tell how can i get next row?? please

Comment: @user3615189 call `rs.next();`again and you get the next row.

Comment: Thanks alot Jens. Just last thing, DELETE query is also not working in netbeans. . . .plz little help

Comment: or see [here](http://www.mkyong.com/jdbc/jdbc-preparestatement-example-delete-a-record/) for an example.

Comment: i have eddited the code in main question body. plz check there

Comment: You have to call `ds.executeUpdate(deletesql);` instead of `ds.executeQuery(deletesql);`

Comment: Int cannot be converted to ResultSet . . . :-( I am beginner, not understanding things quickly.  . . sorry for disturbance, but i  need help plz

Comment: @user3615189 it must be `int i =ds.executeQuery(deletesql);`and you do not get an resultset. You get only the number of deleted rows .

Answer (score 2):

The reason you are getting one column is because you are fetching only one column

```
rs.next();
String sname= rs.getString(2);   //will give you one column
```

instead do

```
while(rs.next){                     //get all rows

 String col1= rs.getString(0);      //get column 1 of respective row
 String col2= rs.getString(1);      //get column 2 of respective row

 System.out.println(col1+" "+col2);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is from rs.getString(2)

Here you have just tried to get the third column. You can use rs.getString(0) and rs.getString(1) to get other values.

Answer (score 0):

**test** table

### col1 col2   col3

col1     1            2   
col2    col11   col21 
col3    col12      col22

you are queries for col1 (i.e. SELECT * FROM test)

String sname= rs.getString(2);
System.out.println(sname);

rs.getString(2) i.e. we are passing column index i.e. second column col2
and it prints the first value in column 2 i.e. 1

here 1 should be printed in reality